# I am trying to move a value to the parent node in a pure function

Tags: javascript, json, functional-programming

I have a JSON (generated by [giftpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gift-pegjs)) and there are some nodes that are useless to me such as "format: "moodle" (see code):

```
[ 
   { 
       "type": "MC", 
       "title": null, 
       "stem": 
           { 
               "format":"moodle", 
               "text": "What is the main cause of the seasons on the earth?" 
           }, 
           "hasEmbeddedAnswers": false, 
           "globalFeedback": null, 
           "choices": 
           [ { 
               "isCorrect": false, 
               "weight": null, 
               "text": 
               { 
                   "format": "moodle", 
                   "text": "the earth's elliptical (slightly oval) orbit around the sun" }, "feedback": null 
               }, 
               { 
                   "isCorrect": true, 
                   "weight": null, 
                   "text": 
                       { "format": "moodle",
                        "text": "the tilt of earth's axis with respect to the sun"
                       },
                       "feedback": null 
               }, 
               { 
                   "isCorrect": false, 
                   "weight": null, 
                   "text": 
                   { 
                       "format": "moodle", 
                       "text": "the northern hemisphere has twice the land mass than the southern hemisphere"
                   }, 
                   "feedback": null
               } 
           ]
   } 
]
```

So far i can remove "format" nodes (I think iam doing it right) but there is some redundancy such as:

```
"text":{
    "text": "foo"
}
```

the goal is to transform it (in a not destructive way) into:

```
"text": "foo"
```

This is my code (trying to be as functional as I can):

```
            formatedQuestions(jsonItem) {
            return jsonItem.map(question => {
                question.choices.map(choice => {
                    delete choice.text.format;
                    choice = Object.assign(choice, choice.text);
                    delete choice.text.text;
                    return choice;
                });
                delete question.stem.format;
                return question;
            });
```

I can move it but it changes the original JSON. So every time i call it it changes. And it is an issue.

This moves the value "up" but it is what changes the original

```
 choice = Object.assign(choice, choice.text);
```

If you have any suggestion besides the solution to make it more functional and efficient will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `Object.assign({}, choice, choice.text);` to create a new object rather than assigning into an existing one?

Comment: Or you can create a new copy of the original object with: `let newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalObj));` and then mutate the `newObj` instead of the original.

Comment: @MarkMeyer: Tried and it does not seem to work. I get the same output as if I weren't running that.

Answer (score 1):

```
 const formatObj = obj => obj.format === "moodle" ? obj.text : Object.entries(obj).reduce((res, [key, value]) => ({ ...res, [key]: format(value) }), {});

 const formatArray = array => array.map(format);

 const format = it => (
   Array.isArray(it) && formatArray(it) ||
   typeof it === "object" && formatObj(it) ||
   it
 );
```

That is functional, wether it is "efficient" or even "readable" is another thing.

How I'd usually do that:

```
 function format(it) {
   if(Array.isArray(it))
     return it.map(format);

   if(typeof it === "object") {
     if(it.format === "moodle")
       return it.text;

     const result = {};
     for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(it))
        result[key] = format(value);
     return result;
   }

   return it;
}
```

---

If you don't need a generic solution here is the specific one for your usecase:

```
 formatedQuestions(jsonItem) {
    return jsonItem.map(question => ({
       ....question,
       stem: question.stem.text,
       choices: question.choices.map(choice => ({
         ...choice,
         text: choice.text.text || choice.text,
       })),
   }));
 }
```

Comment: Wow I was thinking an answer to your first answer and you already wrote 3. Awesome. Let me check it. I am actually developing a quiz app but as a personal challenge I am trying to make as redeable and pure as I can. Thank you.